# CSES food division problem solving approach

Tags: algorithm

Has anyone tried to solve this particular problem? https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1189

Can someone help with an approach?

Comment: Hi there, can you show that code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This works but doesn't optimize the steps

Tried recursion, but since the array 'a' needs to be updated, not sure how recursion can work in this case.

private int findMinSteps(int[] a, int[] b, int n) {
int cnt = 0;

```
do {
  for(int i=1; i <= n; i++) {
    if(a[i] == b[i]) continue;

    if(a[i] > b[i]) { //we can give
      if(a[left(i)] < b[left(i)]) { //give to left
        a[i] -= 1;
        a[left(i)] += 1;
        cnt ++;
      } else /*if(a[right(i)] < b[right(i)])*/ { //give to right
        a[i] -= 1;
        a[right(i)] += 1;
        cnt ++;
      }
    } else { //we have to receive
      if(a[left(i)] > b[left(i)]) { //receive from left`
        a[i] += 1;
        a[left(i)] -= 1;
        cnt ++;
      } else { //receive from right
        a[i] += 1;
        a[right(i)] -= 1;
        cnt ++;
      }
    } //if-else
  } //for
} while(!Arrays.equals(a, b));

return cnt;
```

} //findMinSteps

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive solution that doesn't work either

private int findMinSteps(int[] a, int[] b, int n) {
/*if only one kid or zero kids are there, there is no mis-match
*because the total amount of food is correct
*/

```
//System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
//System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));

if(n < 1)
  return 0;

if(a[n] == b[n])
  return findMinSteps(a, b, n-1);


if(a[n] > b[n]) {
  //At each step a child can give 1 unit of food to neighbor
  int l = left(n);
  int r = right(n);
  
  a[n] -= 1;
  if(a[l] < b[l]) {
   a[l] += 1;
  } else if(a[r] < b[r]) {
    a[r] += 1;
  }

  return 1+findMinSteps(a, b, n-1);
} else
  return findMinSteps(a, b, n-1);
```

}